# How to display in template value of foreign key?

Tags: django

models:

```
class ProductOpinion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    point = models.IntegerField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How to display in my template `point` of my ProductOpinion?

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'products':products}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
{% for p in products %}
  {{ p.point }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: use p.productoptions_set.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If yout want to acces the point field you have to do something like this:

```
{% for p in products %}
  {% for productoption in p.productoptions_set.all %}
      {{ productoption.point }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
{{ p.productopinion_set.all }}
```